# guildMemberRemove not working Discord.js v13.7.0

Tags: javascript, discord.js

New to Discord.js, the `guildMemberAdd` event seems to be working perfectly fine, but it does not detect when a member leaves the guild.

How can I fix this?

```
const { token, guildID, memberChannelID } = require('./config.json');

const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES] });

const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildID)
const prefix = '?';

client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'ping') {
        message.reply('pong!');
    } else if (command === 'help') {
        message.reply('**Commands: ** ?ping, ?membercount');
    } else if (command === 'membercount') {
        message.reply(`There are ${message.guild.memberCount} members in this server!`);
    }
});

client.on('guildMemberAdd', async (member) => {
    client.channels.cache.get(memberChannelID).setName(`Total Members: ${member.guild.memberCount.toLocaleString()}`)
    console.log('Updating Member Count')
})

client.on('guildMemberRemove', async (member) => {
    client.channels.cache.get(memberChannelID).setName(`Total Members: ${member.guild.memberCount.toLocaleString()}`)
    console.log('Updating Member Count')
})

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log("EGLX BOT IS ONLINE")
})

client.login(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the guild member was not cached when the `guildMemberRemove` event is supposed to be emitted, then the issue is probably because you lack the necessary [partials](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/partials.html), an opt-in feature allowing events to emit on uncached structures.  Most likely, you would need the `'GUILD_MEMBER'` partial for the event to emit although you may also need the `'USER'` one if the first doesn't work alone.